# How to remove all the latex from a wikipedia text?

Tags: regex, latex, wikipedia, data-cleaning

I scraped texts from Wikipedia, now I would like to perform text analysis on them. I'd like to remove all the latex from them.

I have tried some regular expression, but unable to find the one that will do the trick.

```
Texts that I want to preserve. Remove the messy latex below.

        2


    {\displaystyle 2}
  ⁄

            3


    {\displaystyle {\sqrt {3}}}
  . I want to preserve some texts here: (Similar latex as above)

    2


    {\displaystyle 2}
  ⁄

            3


    {\displaystyle {\sqrt {3}}}
```

I would expect the result to be all valid texts. In the case above, (Texts that I want to preserve. Remove the messy latex below. I want to preserve some texts here: (Similar latex as above))

Answer (score 1):

With regular expressions, you're going to need a Regex that matches balanced parenthesis `{ ... }`. This is not possible in almost all implementations of Regex, see [Regular expression to match balanced parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546433/regular-expression-to-match-balanced-parentheses)

Instead, you should write a script that reads your file line by line, looks for `{\displaystyle` and locates the corresponding closing curly brace.